# In the table below, how would you retrieve the unique values for the employee_location without using the DISTINCT keyword?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

> Check the below **employee** table which has employee_name & employee_location as columns as shown below:

```
  employee

  employee_name  |  employee_locatio    
    Joe          |   New York   
   Sunil         |   India    
    Alex         |   Russia    
 Albert          |  Canada    
   Jack          |  New York    
   Alex          |  Russia
```

Comment: why would you not use something that is already there? any specific reason?

Comment: School work? Add expected output!

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious what he expects, he is expecting DISTINCT(employee_location) without using Distinct

Comment: Probably, but sometimes people want other columns too (because they don't know better....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` clause

```
select employee_location
from employee
group by employee_location
```

Comment: I hate it when people downvote without feedback, I think it might not be as good as distinct performance wise but it still does the trick

Answer (score 1):

And you can use `UNION`:

```
select employee_location from employee
UNION
select employee_location from employee
```

**Note!** This is just an example of *having fun with SQL*, don't do it in real programming!